# Reading multiple matrices from the same file in R

Tags: r

I know you can use `read.table` to read one matrix from a file, but I would like to read two matrices of the same size (`m` by `n`) from one file in R and put them in two separate R variables.

For example, this file contains two 3 by 2 matrices:

```
6 3
2 5
5 4
4 3
6 3
3 4
```

Comment: You can check out the details of `read.table` to either selectively read in lines from the file twice, OR you can read it all in together and split. File reading is probably the slowest part of that operation, so the latter option is likely faster.

Comment: It's a questionable format, one could say it looks like three 2-by-2 matrices. Why not use one file per matrix? Or add a third column that gives the matrix index.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my shot at it.

```
 split(read.table("data.txt"), gl(2, 3, labels=c("x1", "x2")))
```

It should be easy to generalize this and wrap it up into a function.

I hope this helps.